# Select condition where related rows doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, yii

I am using Yii in the development of an internal administration system for a company. I have created a model `Jobs`, and this model have relations to the model `Quotes` of type HAS_MANY. The relation name is `quotes`. Now i need to select all rows (the model Jobs uses the MySQL table `jobs` as it's source) where each job has exactly 0 quotes associated with it. I thought that i would add this as a scope in the model. How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in model add:

```
public function scopes() {
    return array(
        'withoutQuotes'=>array(
            'with'=>'quotes',
            'condition'=>'quotes.id is null',
        ),
    );
}
```

and then use

```
$model->withoutQuotes()->search() //etc
```